# Upgrading to Rails 7: Where to register the cookie rotator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, hash, openssl

When upgrading from Rails 6 to Rails 7, the `new_framework_defaults_7_0.rb` file [instructs](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/c7fca843a5b8b7a16acd93cf7adbe48c29703470) to register a cookie rotator to read messages using the old digest class using SHA1 (code below). Should this code be executed a single time e.g. in a one-off rake task, or executed in an initializer at each application boot? (And in the latter case should it be enclosed in an after_initialize block as suggested [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/44047)?) How to figure out whether there are other places where such a migration is needed in the app besides cookies?

```rb
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.cookies_rotations.tap do |cookies|
  salt = Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.authenticated_encrypted_cookie_salt
  secret_key_base = Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base
  key_generator = ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator.new(
    secret_key_base, iterations: 1000, hash_digest_class: OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1
  )
  key_len = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.key_len
  secret = key_generator.generate_key(salt, key_len)
  cookies.rotate :encrypted, secret
end
```

Comment: On application boot.

Comment: Thank you @max, how long do you recommend to keep this rotator in the application initializers? I guess after a while (a few weeks?) any old user will have rotated their cookies and the initializer can be removed?

Comment: I dunno. Provided that you're just using cookies for authentication the worst thing that can happen is that the users have to log back in since thier cookie would be invalidated and not rotated.

Comment: `config/initializers/cookie_rotator.rb` https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/guides/source/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.md#key-generator-digest-class-changing-to-use-sha256